# Share with Facebook Messenger

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have updated the dependency of Facebook SDK to 4.1.0. They changed a lot and now I cannot find a way to share text and image with Messenger.

Before updating the sdk I was using:

```
FacebookDialog.MessageDialogBuilder builder = new FacebookDialog.MessageDialogBuilder(this)
            .setName(linkName)
            .setDescription(description)
            .setLink(webLink)
            .setPicture(pictureLink);

    FacebookDialog dialog = builder.build();
    dialog.present();
```

Now looks like I can only share images.

```
String mimeType = "image/jpeg";
ShareToMessengerParams shareToMessengerParams =
        ShareToMessengerParams.newBuilder(contentUri, mimeType)
                .build();
MessengerUtils.shareToMessenger(
       this,
       REQUEST_CODE_SHARE_TO_MESSENGER,
       shareToMessengerParams);
```

Can anyone explain a equivalent way to share text and image as before 4.1.0 please?

Comment: This will not help you much, but I stopped adding special support for facebook a long time ago, when it was clear that they don't support the normal SHARE-intent correctly. Everything would be so easy, but Facebook app intentionally does not use subject and text one can add as extras to the SHARE-intent. So, there, Facebook, you don't get anything shared from my apps :-)

Comment: Daniele, you can't auto-fill the text to share any more. You can share Links, Images, Videos but the user has to type in the text.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found out that there is a similar way to share on Facebook which works also for Messenger.

Here is the code

```
ShareLinkContent.Builder shareLinkContentBuilder = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
            .setContentTitle(contentTitle)
            .setContentDescription(contentDescription)
            .setContentUrl(Uri.parse(url));
    shareLinkContentBuilder.setImageUrl(Uri.parse(imageUrl));
    MessageDialog messageDialog = new MessageDialog(activity);
    messageDialog.registerCallback(callbackManager, callback);
    messageDialog.show(shareLinkContentBuilder.build());
```

The relative doc is under *Sharing* section and not *Messenger* one
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android

Comment: Currently deprecated

Comment: `setContentDescription/setContentTitle/setImageUrl` all is Deprecated

As of Graph API 2.9 this field is deprecated and may not function as expected.
For more information, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_9_deprecations.
Set the URL of a picture to attach to this content.

Answer (score 0):

After I saw everything is deprecated in my case I only need to share 2 images, so the intent method works without Facebook SDK.

"String pack" is the messenger package name, can be one of both :

Messenger: com.facebook.orca

Messenger Lite: com.facebook.mlite

```
public void shareToOtherAppByPackage(Context context, String pack, Bitmap bitmap1,Bitmap bitmap2) {
    try {

        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes1 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap1.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes1);
        String path1 = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(context.getContentResolver(), bitmap1, "front", null);
        Uri imageUri1 = Uri.parse(path1);

        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes2 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap2.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes2);
        String path2 = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(context.getContentResolver(), bitmap2, "back", null);
        Uri imageUri2 = Uri.parse(path2);

        //PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
        //PackageInfo info = pm.getPackageInfo(pack, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);


        ArrayList<Uri> imageUris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
        imageUris.add(imageUri1); // Add your image URIs here
        imageUris.add(imageUri2);


        Intent shareIntent  = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
        shareIntent.setType("image/*");
        shareIntent.setPackage(pack);
        shareIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUris);

        //waIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, pack); // adds text to share
        context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent , context.getString(R.string.share_with)));
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(context, context.getString(R.string.app_share_not_installed), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```